# How to send a custom notification without an actual redirect?

Tags: apex, community, lightning-experience, notification, digital-experience

I want some of my users to notify group of users on the community as well as internal users about new features that we implement every month. These are purely informational  notifications and don't necessarily require a redirect. I tried using the [CustomNotification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Messaging_CustomNotification.htm) but it always requires either a `Target Id` or a `Target Page Reference`. I tried using `standard__webPage` as below :

```
notification.setTargetPageRef('{ "type": "standard__webPage", "attributes": { "url": "http://#" }}');
```

This gives me an error  `This page isn't available...` and the URL formed for internal users is
`<orgsandboxurl>/lightning/webpage/http%3A%2F%2F%23`.

Further I tried using `notification.setTargetPageRef('{ "type": "standard__webPage", "attributes": { "url": "/#" }}');` and it refreshes the page for internal users.

How can I make this work without actually navigating or refreshing the page ?
Alternatively, do we have any other techniques to notify users without having to do a lot of customisation ?

Answer (score 2):

As you already mentioned, you must specify either a `targetId` or a `targetPageRef`.

In your case, if you don't want to redirect the user to any page, simply set dummy id for `targetId`. This is also explicitly mentioned in the [CustomNotification Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Messaging_CustomNotification.htm)

> You must specify a target for a notification. The target can be
> specified using either the targetID or the targetPageRef attribute.
> Neither attribute is required, but if both are omitted, send() throws
> an exception. If there’s no natural target for a notification, set the
> targetID to a dummy value, such as 000000000000000AAA. A dummy value
> prevents the exception, and also prevents automatic navigation when
> responding to the notification in the client app.

**Apex**

```
notification.setTargetId('000000000000000AAA');
```